# Prevent multiple form submission using a counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**P.S -** Although there are many other such questions in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+prevent+form+from+submitting+multiple+times+), I could NOT find the method that I was trying to implement.

Now, what I tried doing is as follows :-

**Profile Page**

```
Email : example@example.com      [Edit Details Button]
```

**Edit Details Page** //user is sent here if s/he clicks on *Edit Details Button*

```
<form id='inputform'>

<input type="text" name="email" id='email'>
<button type="submit" id='submitform'>Submit</button>

</form>

<script>

 //Script part below

</script>
```

**Script**

```
//validation part here

var noofsubmits = 0;
$('#submitform').on('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();


   if($('#inputform').valid()){

    noofsubmits++;
     if(noofsubmits == 1){
     $('#inputform').submit();
     //redirect users to a different page on successful form submission
  }
}

});
```

On every form submit, the user is redirected to the profile page (which shows updated info). Now, everytime the user tries to edit details , the varialbe `noofsubmits`  is set to `0`.

I am not having any problem with this method, but is there any practical problem with this method? Like what if the user disables **Javascript** in the browser, so would this method not work?

Comment: the alternative to counter would be, disabling the submit button. irrespectively, you have to check the form re-submission validation on the server for good design.

Comment: @nivendha **you have to check the form re-submission validation on the server for good design.** What do you mean by this?

Comment: https://github.com/caxap/jquery-safeform try this jQuery plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes for sure if javascript is disabled on the client side, the script part will not be executed. (and you have to do validation and redirection on the server side)

However, there are very very few people who disable javascript in their browser.

The drawback of doing validation and redirection on the server side is that the user will need to wait for a slightly longer time because there will be time lag before the server respondes to the client request. But if your validation is done on the client side (javascript), then the user will experience immediate response on data validation.

On the other hand, using javascript will also be good if you want some visual effect like animation to be rendered on the client side.

Since very very few people will disable javascript in their browser, you can continue to use your javascript approach to do the job

Comment: Some answers in other Stackoverflow forums used `attr['disabled']` which disables the submit button. Is that method better or faster or more convenient than the one that I used?

Comment: Just be aware that only validating on the client-side can be a huge security vulnerabilty. Make sure to validate things on the server-side, too.

Comment: I think both your method and disabling the submit button will have the same effect. No need to use their method as long as you are happy with your noofsubmits count method

Comment: @JosefWittmann Yes, I was only showing the code on client side and that too an example, just to show my concept.